# What are your best practices for C++ exception handling?

Tags: c++, logging, exception, coding-style

I searched the Internet and found a lot of articles about this topic. However, I found there is no complete checklist to verify our code's quality of exception-safety.

So, I want to collect valuable best practices for C++ exception handling from you.

I first list some practices of my own:

1. Catch all exceptions if any in destructors:

   ```
   struct A
   {
       ~A()
       {
           try
           {
               // Here may throw exceptions
           }
           catch (std::runtime_error& e)
           {}
           catch (...)
           {
               logging("...");
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. Add function name, source file name and line numer in exception information. `__func__`, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are good friends.
3. Never use exception specifications. The reason is given in the book "C++ Coding Standards".

What are yours?

Comment: Actually, `__func__` is a good friend. We're all shunning `__FUNCTION__` because it's not in the standard.

Comment: Throw by value catch by const reference.

Comment: @AlokSave, why const? Non-const reference catch is better!

Comment: @hate-engine: What makes you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Non-const means possible copying meaning possible std::bad_alloc meaning std::terminate.. const ftw

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know this may better fit as a comment than as an answer, but since the resource I'm linking answers *all* of your questions and **more**, I thought it would be OK to post it as an answer as well, just to give it more visibility and/or relevance.

And since I couldn't possibly sum it all up better than the original does, I'm not even going to try and do a short summary, because I would risk to distort it or give a biased overview.

Just watch this **[two-part talk on exception-safe coding by Jon Kalb](http://www.exceptionsafecode.com/)**. That's it.